# Branching/Looping in Gridview-Scrollviewer for Winrt

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, scrollviewer

Weird question, How can I implement branching in the Gridview Scrollviewer?

I'm using ListViewBase.ScrollIntoView to handle the event for No and scroll into "Screen End". But, I'm stuck on how to handle the Yes on Screen5.

> Scenario: (--> = Swipe/Scroll  || "Screens" are items in a scrollable
>   gridview)
>
> ```
> Screen1 --> Screen2
> Screen2 --> Screen3
> Screen 3 has Yes/No question
> Clicking No goes to **Screen End**.
> Clicking Yes goes to Screen 4,
> Screen4 --> Screen5
> Screen5 has Yes/No question.
> Clicking No Goes to **Screen End**.
> Clicking Yes goes to screen 6, 
> Screen 6-->Screen 2.
> ```

Swipe/Scroll back on Screen 2 should go to Screen 6.

Comment: You need to describe what you need in more detail. It's unclear what you expect to happen from your notes.

Comment: @FilipSkakun

Think about the Store. you have 1000 app's/games listed there. At one moment 100(1 screen) apps are displayed on screen and you slide right to go to next 100(screen 2) . Lets say on apps in the range of 500-600(screen 5) you have a button which takes you to apps in range of 200-300(screen 2). I achieve this by ListViewBase.ScrollIntoView(200).   But, now swiping to left will take me to apps in range of 0-100, how do I make it go to  apps in range of 500-600?

Comment: I think you'll need to implement a custom control similar to, but different than a ScrollViewer.